# Duplicate file index.d.ts in visual studio 2017 solution

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2017

After some point lots of duplicates appear in my solution containing a nodejs project. Duplicates refer all to the file C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts

I added and removes typescript projects, so have to be related to that. Build works fine, build log end with no errors, still i have 366 errors on Error list Tab. I am tempting to just delete file.

Update:
Found out that deep in on of node.js project structure was the same file. Still i don't know if deleting the version in AppData folder is the right procedure.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 months happen again, but probably by a different cause. This time  i the cause was that i open the **compiled js files**.

Since i had the setting  `"compileOnSave": true, Visual studio could read controller.js file (generated from controller.ts file) and somehow decided to append types into index.d.ts file.

The first error of an 170 error list show that visual studio could not write controller.js also with other js files that i was inspecting.

Closing controller.js file and other js files make all the 170 errors disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Visual Studio 17 to latest version fixed this issue for me.